# How to use git locally and push to remote server

Tags: git, drupal

I want to use git to manage my development, integration test and production environments.  I've looked around but can't seem to find a simple explanation of how (eg [Git - pushing to remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151218/git-pushing-to-remote-repository) doesn't quite do it).  A very brief explanation of what I want to do:

- I master my codebase on my laptop as that's where I do most of my work.
- I host my site on 1and1.  On there, I have two sites set up, the production site and an integration test site.
- I want to set up git so I can have two remotes on my laptop, say siteprod and siteint.
- Whenever I have a branch I want to test, I want to push it from my laptop, say using "git push siteprod newproductionversion" (I'm sure you get the idea).

I've achieved something close by creating a repository on 1and1 using git --init (note without --bare!) and setting up the remotes using ssh.  But I have to set receive.denyCurrentBranch to ignore and once I've pushed, I have to checkout the branch by logging onto the 1and1 server.  I have to repeat it all for the integration environment.

This seems very clumsy but I'm sure my use case is not at all unusual.  Is there a sensible way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have ssh connection to the server, you can add a git remote directly to the repository on the server.  Something like:

```
git add remote production sshUser@example.com:/path/to/repo/.git
```

Then, to deploy,

```
git push production branch
```

That said, you probably shouldn't have your production code served from a git repository.  Much better is to set up a repository *outside* your web root and use a `post-receive` hook to copy the code to the web root.  This appears to be outlined here:
[Deploy a project using Git push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279169/deploy-a-project-using-git-push)

Comment: Thanks.  You pointed me in the direction where I eventually found the perfect solution here: http://blog.woodylabs.com/2012/01/1and1-web-hosting-git-installing-it-for-singular-dev/ (it's a little specific for 1and1 but references the original idea which isn't).  Now my problem is how I also push submodules! :o)

Answer (score 1):

Git is not (originally) meant for synchronizing working copies but repositories that is Git's commits/branches/refs/etc.

What your  want to do I would call a remote checkout. There is hundreds of other ways to do. I have two ideas: As you have setup an ssh-connection the big work is done:

1) use git and ssh

```
git push origin my_branch
ssh user@server "(cd remote-dir-where-your-repo-is; git checkout -f my_branch;)"
```

2) Use rsync

```
rsync -av . ssh://user@server/dir --exclude=.git
```