# Best way to backup a Drupal Website

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

My first Drupal project is about doing some maintenance and adding code to an existing Drupal Website.

What is the best scenario to have a backup of database and code. If something goes wrong, I want to recover the website from these backups.

> Actually, I'm doing backup of Drupal database via phpMyAdmin, and
>   backup of code via FTP (copying all the content of public_html folder)

The website is actually on production, users add contents, chat...

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you do regular (say) daily backups using cron with the module Anis suggested.

As for backing up your code, I think it's essential you use a configuration management system such as git so you can always go back to any point in your development cycle without worrying about explicit backups. I use git locally and push to my production environment as discussed here: [How to use git locally and push to remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901679/how-to-use-git-locally-and-push-to-remote-server) and the links pointed to in the responses.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a a drupal module for do that like [Backup migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate)

Also you can backup website manually, go to database ... truncate all table caches ..then export database..,  then get a copy from file ..

good luck ..